# gcc -O3 , data pointer seems to get lost

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

Depending on optimization level the output differ as follows:

With unexpected output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -O3  otest.c -o otest                   
$ otest                                             
*x: 0 
y: 2048.899902 
y: 0.000000
```

With expected output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -O2  otest.c -o otest 
$ otest                           
*x: 45000e66 
y: 0.000000 
y: 2048.899902
```

source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   float y = 2048.9;
   void *p = &y;
   unsigned int *x = p;
   printf(" *x: %x \n",*x);
   *x = 0; 
   printf(" y: %f \n",y);
   *x = 0x45000e66;
   printf(" y: %f \n",y);  
   return 0;
 }
```

gcc version is 4.2.1.

Am I missing any important directive ?

Comment: `-fno-strict-aliasing`

Comment: @MarcGlisse Don't even suggest that. **Ever.**

Comment: @user3477950 I think that's a good keyword to look for further information on the net. If the OP still wants to use it, that's his problem...

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes, but your comment suggests that it's a **solution.** It is not.

Comment: -fno-strict-aliasing solved the problem!

Comment: @ole in case it wasn't clear, a random word in a comment is not a "solution" or a "recommendation", it is advice on what to type in your search engine to get more information and understand in what ways your code is wrong.

Comment: union is better in aliasing cases like this

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: No, it is not. Reading union via different type than you set it is just as undefined behaviour as this. The only exception is if one of the types is `char`.

Comment: @JanHudec It's not undefined behavior. **You are confusing pointer-based type punning** (which is UB unless the aliasing type is signed or unsigned `char`) **with union-based type punning** (which is **not** undefined behavior since C99).

Comment: @user3477950: It is undefined behaviour in C++ though.

Comment: @JanHudec Yes, it is. However, the question is about C, not C++.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Your code is violating the strict aliasing rule (when you have a `float`, but you access it through a pointer to `unsigned int`, which is an incompatible type), invoking undefined behavior, so the compiler is allowed to do anything it pleases with your code, including entirely eliminating parts of it.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that compilers these days do try to do the right thing -- they'll generate their code presuming circumstances that would lead to undefined behavior don't exist, which can open up quite a lot of optimization opportunities...